# mySQLd: Out of Memory (please take a look at my error.log)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, out-of-memory, shutdown

I don't know what went wrong, but mysql shutdown and wouldn't restart until I restarted the entire server.

I'm running a small droplet via Digital Ocean. It is 1GB of memory droplet.

Here is the error.log from var/log/mysql

```
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128663552 bytes)
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96485376 bytes)
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Warning] InnoDB: innodb_open_files 300 should not be greater than the open_files_limit 155
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(134217728 bytes) failed; errno 12
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2020-05-13 11:12:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
double free or corruption (out)
200513 11:12:40 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic
key_buffer_size=16384
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=32
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 11022 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x3c000
2020-05-13 15:42:45 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_co$
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Warning] InnoDB: innodb_open_files 300 should not be greater than the open_files_limit 155
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all system tablespace files open for the whole t$
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all system tablespace files open for the whole t$
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all system tablespace files open for the whole t$
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=54398070
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-13 15:43:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-13 15:43:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.12 started; log sequence number 54398079; transaction id 57334
2020-05-13 15:43:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-13 15:43:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-13 15:43:17 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2020-05-13 15:43:17 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2020-05-13 15:43:17 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Warning] InnoDB: innodb_open_files 300 should not be greater than the open_files_limit 155
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all system tablespace files open for the whole t$
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all system tablespace files open for the whole t$
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all system tablespace files open for the whole t$
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.12 started; log sequence number 54398088; transaction id 57334
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-05-13 15:48:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200513 15:48:57
2020-05-13 15:49:02 118 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './data_pg/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-05-13 15:49:02 118 [Warning] Checking table:   './data_pg/wp_options'
2020-05-13 15:49:04 154 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './data_pia/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-05-13 15:49:04 154 [Warning] Checking table:   './data_pia/wp_options'
2020-05-13 15:51:01 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2020-05-13 15:51:01 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-05-13 15:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-05-13 15:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-05-13 15:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-13 15:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200513 15:51:01
2020-05-13 15:51:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 54398097; transaction id 57335
2020-05-13 15:51:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-05-13 15:51:02 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Warning] InnoDB: innodb_open_files 300 should not be greater than the open_files_limit 155
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of s$
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all s$
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all s$
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Warning] InnoDB: You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf! Remember that InnoDB keeps all log files and all s$
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.12 started; log sequence number 54398097; transaction id 57334
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-05-13 15:51:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200513 15:51:03
2020-05-13 15:58:38 198 [Warning] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-05-13 17:09:16 466 [Warning] Access denied for user 'ADMIN'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-05-13 17:10:18 473 [Warning] Access denied for user 'ADMIN'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-05-13 17:22:59 542 [Warning] Access denied for user 'ADMIN'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It tells me "You must raise the value of innodb_open_files in my.cnf!" 
Is this what the problem is? If it is, what value you do I raise this too?

Your help is highly appreciated.

edit: I have total memory 985M and available 413M

Edit: my.cnf

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

symbolic-links=0
local-infile=0

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 10
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 240K

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table

max_connections=30
max_user_connections=20
wait_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=5

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: where is it now? it seems you played around with the settings already

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "where is it now?"

Comment: i mean innodb_open_files because 300 are to high as your log already shows there is already a formula to check if your parameters are not right, so do the math.

Comment: In my.cnf I don't even have any open_files parameters set
I added my.cnf to the thread for reference

Comment: then add it with 155 as number and see if it still gets out of Memory and decrease it firther, mysql mariadb, tell you if they fnd something not right

Comment: Ok I added open_files_limit=155 to my.cnf. We will see what happens if I get an error. Thanks